# JQuery autocomplete function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have work on autocomplete function which work fine for me,
now I want to call autocomplete function on click event which show the same list.
I don't want to repeat the same work on click event which I have done on autocomplete event
because it is to long.

Thanks in advance for your time and help

Comment: try posting some code you've tried in a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to give examples without knowing the autocomplete plugin being used. I'm guessing jQuery UI Autocomplete. Let me know, if that's not the case.

```
$('#autocomplete-field').focus(function() {
    // no need to search if dropdown is already active
    if ($('ul.ui-autocomplete').is(':hidden')) { 
        $(this).autocomplete('search', '');
    }
});
```

This way, we'll trigger autocompleter when the field gets focus (and clicked). 
This code is untested. Let me know if it works.

Comment: there is another search button for which I want call the autocomplete event,
the above code might not work for what I want